# HTTPS with certificate

Tags: webdav

I have HTTPS server configured in LAN.

When I upload a file to this HTTPS server with certificate using curl. File get uploaded.

If I do not specify the certificate and use the "-k" or "--insecure" switch then also files get uploaded to server.

Now, is there any way to list out which files are uploaded on server by using certificates and which are the files uploaded without certificate ?

I had configured HTTPS server (webdav) on both Ubuntu-14.04 as well as on Windows 8

Answer (score 2):

Yes, start by filtering your access.log with http and POST like that:

Accesses with HTTP:

```
grep http /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep -v https | grep POST
```

Accesses with HTTPS:

```
grep https /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep POST
```

Comment: Why **HTTP** ?  I am uploading the files by HTTPS protocol only. Once with certificate and once without certificate. I am not using HTTP protocol, then what's the point for grepping HTTP ?

Comment: Well, looking to logs is not only to see what you're expecting for, but specially to look what you are not expecting for, so...  an developer error or a error that you do, can be detected with it.